# Loading from list of tuples fails

Tags: python-polars

i am trying to load a list of tuples into pl.Dataframe:

```
data = [(1, UUID('some-uuid'), None, datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 6, 18, 11), None, 24040228, None, 0.0625, False, <Fruit.BANANA: 'BANANA'>, None),]
pl.DataFrame(data, orient='row')
```

will result in:

### column_0

### object

(1, UUID('3231989-c122-222b-1cf… │

instead of a Dataframe with multiple columns for each value i get a single column with an tuple inside.

Note the enum is a StrEnum.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Which polars version are you using?

Comment: If you maintain a column with an Object type, you're going to have a bad time. Just keep make it a string and avoid the headache.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using polars version `0.20.6` gives the expected result.

```py
from enum import StrEnum
from uuid import UUID

import polars as pl
import datetime

class Fruit(StrEnum):
    BANANA = 'banana'


data = [
    (1, UUID('a17ad043-486f-5eeb-8138-8fa2b10659fd'), None, datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 6, 18, 11), None, 24040228, None, 0.0625, False, Fruit.BANANA, None),
]
pl.DataFrame(data, orient='row')
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (1, 11)
┌──────────┬───────────────────────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1                          ┆ column_2 ┆ column_3            ┆ column_4 ┆ column_5 ┆ column_6 ┆ column_7 ┆ column_8 ┆ column_9 ┆ column_10 │
│ ---      ┆ ---                               ┆ ---      ┆ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ i64      ┆ object                            ┆ null     ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ null     ┆ i64      ┆ null     ┆ f64      ┆ bool     ┆ str      ┆ null      │
╞══════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ a17ad043-486f-5eeb-8138-8fa2b106… ┆ null     ┆ 2023-02-03 06:18:11 ┆ null     ┆ 24040228 ┆ null     ┆ 0.0625   ┆ false    ┆ banana   ┆ null      │
└──────────┴───────────────────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: I am also using 0.20.6

The behavior is very weird and might have to do something with SqlAlchemy. 

I am doing this query: all_data = db.session.execute(db.select(SomeTable.__table__).limit(5)).fetchall() 

which leads to the data you've seen. Then i try to load it with polars. if i pass to polars the columns it says there is a dimension missmatch however pandas works out of the box without colnames with correct result. 

The super weird thing is, that pandas knows about the column names, which it shouldn't. I've inspected all_data and the result is a list of tuples with no col names.

Comment: @zacko Does the example above run as expected? In this case, it seems like the issue is that SqlAlchemy doesn’t return what you think it does. This would also explain pandas accessing the column names. You could open a new question with more details on SQLAlchemy. As asked right now. the question is solved, no?

Comment: The above example does work. I defaulted to pl.from_dicts([ row._asdict() for row in all_records]), however i wish i could avoid the iteration. The issue is that it's not really a tuple as first expected when priting it out, but rather a sqlalchemy Row. Pandas magically know how to extract it, however polars aint there yet. Also sqlalchemy isnt like django, django gives u the option to get values instead of row objects.